# Bitcoin transaction charges

Tags: transaction-fees

I have a broker with a questionable reputation who is trying to send me a couple of BTC, but maintains there is a transaction charge of c$25k for this to go ahead. I don't believe him and think this is a scam but would appreciate opinions on what is a reasonable transaction fee to receive 3BTC and the drivers that influence the costs.

Comment: What does "c$25k" mean? 25000 USD cents?

Comment: Maybe Canadian Dollars? Either way, no, he's trying to scam you. I linked your question to a topic that covers this sort of situation.

Comment: If they're legitimate, they will take whatever fee they need out of the amount they are sending you. *Anybody* who asks you to send them money on the promise that they will then send you money is trying to scam you.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, confirms what I thought.